# How to find the probability density function by the joint distribution?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

$f$ is a jointly continuous distribution function
$f(x,y)=Cx^2 y^2$   where       $0<y<1$,$y^3<x<y^{1/3}$

C is a constant.

Find $f_X (x)$ and $f_{(X|Y)} (x│y)$

This is not a homework but a practice question.

---

My work：

$f_X(x)=\int_\infty f(x,y)dy=\int_0^1Cx^2y^2dy=\frac{1}{3}Cx^2$

To find $C$, we assume $\int_0^1\int_{y^3}^{y^{1/3}}f(x,y)dxdy=1$

$C=18$?

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: Sure, I will update it very soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write $f$ properly. You can write :

$$ f(x,y) = Cx^2y^2 \mathbb I_{\{0 \leqslant y \leqslant 1 \}} \mathbb I_{\{y^3 \leqslant x \leqslant y^{1/3}\}} $$

Therefore :

$$ f_X(x) = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x,y) dy =  \int_{\mathbb R} Cx^2y^2 \mathbb I_{\{0 \leqslant y \leqslant 1 \}} \mathbb I_{\{y^3 \leqslant x \leqslant y^{1/3}\}} dy  $$

Which leads to :

$$ f_X(x) = Cx^2 \mathbb I_{\{0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1 \}} \int_0^1 y^2 \mathbb I_{\{y^3 \leqslant x \leqslant y^{1/3}\}} dy  $$

Also $ y^3 \leqslant x \leqslant y^{1/3} \Leftrightarrow x^3 \leqslant y \leqslant x^{1/3}$. Therefore :

$$ f_X(x) = Cx^2 \int_{x^3}^{x^{1/3}} y^2 dy = Cx^2 \left[ \frac{y^3}{3}\right]_{x^3}^{x^{1/3}} = C\frac{x^2}{3}(x - x^6) $$

To find $f_{X|Y}$ I suggest you do the same for $f_Y$ and use Bayes formula.